# Add active class to nav link for first JSON data Object initially using Angular JS

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angularjs, json

Add active class to the nav link for the first JSON object which is initially shown before selecting any nav link.

**https://embed.plnkr.co/cI2QXbUgtnbwH5qe5CKj/**

**My HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title>RichMedia Portfolio</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular-route.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="richPortfolio">



<div class="container" ng-controller="adsCtrl">
    <nav>
        <ul class="accordion" onclick="myFunction(event)">
            <li ng-repeat="ad in ads">
                <a class="ad" href="" id="ad{{ ad.id }}" ng-click="select(ad)">{{ ad.title }}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="showCase_container">
        <div id="ad{{ selectedItem.id }}Case" class="adActive">
            <div class="description">
                <h3 class="ad_name">{{ selectedItem.title }}</h3>
                <p>{{selectedItem.content}}</p>
                <hr>
                <h3>Description</h3>
                <p>{{ selectedItem.desc }}</p>
                <hr>
                <h3>Dimension</h3>
                <p>{{ selectedItem.dim }}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="rich.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**My Js:**

```
// Modules

var rich = angular.module('richPortfolio', ['ngRoute']);

rich.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            controller: 'adsCtrl',
            templateUrl: 'pages/home.html'
        })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
});

// controllers

rich.controller('adsCtrl', ['$scope', 'ads', function($scope, ads , element){
    ads.then(function(data){
        $scope.ads = data;
        $scope.selectedItem = data[0];
    });

    // nav redirection
    $scope.select = function(item) {
        $scope.selectedItem = item;  
    };

}]);

//services

rich.factory('ads', ['$http', function($http){

    // after v1.6 need to use .then function to get it worked
    return $http.get('ads.json')
            .then(function(response){
                //alert('success');
                return data = response.data;
            },function(error){
                //alert('error');
            });

}]);

function myFunction(e) {
  var elems = document.querySelector(".accordion .active");
  if(elems !==null){
   elems.classList.remove("active");
  }
 e.target.className = "active";
}
```

**My JSON:**

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "title": "cube",
    "content": "cube 1 cube",
    "desc":"orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit",
    "dim":"300x250"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "title": "Gallery",
    "content": "Gallery 2 Gallery",
    "desc":"orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit",
    "dim":"300x250, 300x600, 728x90, 970x250"
  }
]
```

All I need is to add the active class to the title of the initial JSON object data at the nav bar.
**https://embed.plnkr.co/cI2QXbUgtnbwH5qe5CKj/**

Any Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use ng-class with index to make first tab active like below syntax 
`<li ng-repeat="ad in ads" ng-class="{'active':$index===0}></li>`

Comment: Thanks, @deepica it working perfectly. I'm still at beginner level. Getting a lot of doubts. Can you please suggest me few links from where I can master Angular Js on real-time scenarios like this one.